# How do I create a resource that is the sub-set of an existing resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-routing

In my "routes.rb" file I have the following line:

```
resource :users
```

which gives me a bunch of named routes for accessing my User model in a RESTful manner.

Now, I've made some additions to the User model including creating a special class of user. These are still stored in the User model but there is a "special" flag in the database that identifies them as special.

So, is it possible to create special_users resource? For example, I'd like to have a "special_users_path" as a named route to "/special_users" which will return an index of only the special users when you perform a GET on the URL.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails routing, a 'resource' refers to the standard 7 routes that are created for RESTful resources: `index`, `show`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`. Normally that is enough, but sometimes you might want to create another action.

In the model, you want to create a `scope` that only returns special users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :special, where(:special => true)
end
```

On the controller side, there are two ways to go about this. What you are suggesting is the creation of an additional action:

```
match "/users/special" => "users#special"  
resource :users
```

In the controller, your special action would return the scope you just created:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def special
    @users = User.special
  end
end
```

That will do what you ask, but I would suggest NOT doing it this way. What if you add other flags later that you want to search by? What if you want to search by multiple flags? This solution isn't flexible enough for that. Instead, keep the routes the way they are:

```
resource :users
```

and just add an additional line to your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @users = @users.special if params[:special]
  end
end
```

and now, when you want to display special users, simply direct the user to `/users?special=true`

This approach is much more future-proof, IMO.

(This answer is assuming Rails-3. If you're still using 2.3 let me know)

Comment: There's no need for the lambda in your first example. This will do: scope: special, where(special: true)

Comment: @noodl Thanks, still getting accustomed to arel.

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful explanation and I really appreciate you going to the trouble to show an alternate method as well as the trivial case.

Comment: @spinlock btw, my placing the `match` line above the `resource` line is important; otherwise 'special' will be interpreted as an id value and the special action will never to routed to.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the special_users as a resource:

```
resource :special_users
```

If you need to point it to a special controller, you could specify it with:

```
resource :special_users, :controller => :users
```

But I would really suggest you to not creating another controller for retrieving a kind of user, but using a param to get them:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
     users = case params[:type].to_s
               when "special"
                 User.special_users # Using named scopes
               else
                 User.all
             end
   end
 end
```

When you use the users_path to call the special users:

```
users_path(:type => :special)
```